# How do you use script# to create a jQuery plugin?

Tags: c#, jquery, script#

The only example of a simple script# jQuery plugin I could find online is here:

http://groups.google.com/group/scriptsharp_coding/browse_thread/thread/40769da17b0bb8d2?pli=1

The JQuery object from ScriptSharp 0.7.3 does not appear to expose a `fn` property or method though, so I am not sure how to continue.

Has anyone done this before, and could possibly give me a few tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry for the initial trivial search. This page nicely explains how to do a jq plugin with script#:

http://michaelmurray75.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/getting-started-with-jquery-plugins-with-mvc-and-script/

You can get the whole code [here](https://github.com/michaelmurray/The-Heap/tree/master/ScrollPager)

Comment: This is the exact text from the link I posted, that does not compile in v. 0.7.3. For instance, jQuery is declared `sealed` and cannot be inherited from. I believe this example was written before offical jQuery support.

Comment: No problem bud, this looks much much more like what I was after. Can you tell me what terms you used to look it up, because I never found this.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!'

Comment: Though I am very confused about this script#. why would you want to write c# classes and convert them to JavaScript at runtime?

Comment: It's done at compile time, not runtime. The script# stuff is kept in a separate project, that produces .js files when it's compiled for you to consume in your main project.